# ctypes vs pure python

Tags: python, performance, ctypes

Why ctypes is slower in my code than pure python for to increment a variable ?

```
from ctypes import *
import timeit

def f1():
    global t
    t += 1

def f2():
    p[0] += 1

t = 0
n = c_int(0)
p = pointer(n)

print(timeit.timeit("f1()", setup="from __main__ import f1")) # 0.3417885800008662
print(timeit.timeit("f2()", setup="from __main__ import f2")) # 0.5280102270189673

print(t) # 1000000
print(n.value) # 1000000
```

How to increase the speed with ctypes module ?

Comment: Perhaps an interesting read: http://tungwaiyip.info/blog/2009/07/16/ctype_performance_benchmark

Comment: `p[0]` calls `PyObject_GetItem` on the pointer, which calls the pointer's `tp_as_mapping.mp_subscript`, which is `Pointer_subscript`, which calls `Pointer_item`, which computes the offset for the 0th item and gets the type's `getfunc`, `i_get` (signed C `int`), and then calls `PyCData_get`, which calls `i_get` with the base address and size, which copies the value to a C `int` on the stack and calls `PyInt_FromLong` to return a Python `int`.

Comment: The Python `int` gets incremented the same as with `t`. The result is stored back via `PyObject_SetItem`, which calls the pointer's `tp_as_sequence.sq_ass_item`, which is `Pointer_ass_item`, which computes the offset for the 0th item and gets the type's `setfunc`, `i_set`, and then calls `PyCData_set`, which calls `i_set` with the base address, value, and size, which gets the value as a C `long` from `PyInt_AsUnsignedLongMask`, which it casts as a C `int` and copies to the target address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual increment is a very simple operation and is unlikely to be taking most of the time. More likely it's the function calls themselves, and in the case of `f2` you have the overhead of calling into ctypes.

Ctypes can provide performance gains by allowing you to implement non-trivial, CPU intensive parts of your program in C or C++.

Comment: It is clear, but i thought I was using perhaps not correctly ctypes. Thanks !